# Что означают эти две ошибки в консоли разработчика?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

GET chrome-extension://pldjobpacmbpflpemnmgdiccchjgdhpe/content/styles.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Второе - видимо ошибка получения файла у какого-то расшерения.

Comment: Возможно и первое тоже, если оно попыталось встроить какой-то свой скрипт. В общем — отключайте браузерные расширения

Comment: К слову, расширение с таким идентификатором в хромовском магазине сейчас отсутствует. Либо было раньше, но удалено по тем или иным причинам, либо установлено не из магазина.

Comment: Расширение в браузере у вас мешается. Выключите все и включите поочереди снова. У меня было такое, что просто надо было их все ребутнуть)